# php mysql query a table for the last set number of rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to construct a `mysql_query` that will  give me only new `rows`  inserted in a `table` with a `where condition` like ....

```
SELECT (LAST 5) FROM `x`  WHERE `USER_KEY` = '$RK' ORDER BY `dd` DESC
```

this data will be parsed in json afterwards,otherwise i would have just got all the data and looped threw.

Answer (score 2):

you can reverse the order and get the first 5. That is the same as getting the last 5 and sorting the other way around

```
SELECT * FROM `x`  WHERE `USER_KEY` = '$RK' ORDER BY `dd` ASC limit 5
```

or if you need the desc order you can do

```
select * from (SELECT * FROM `x`  
               WHERE `USER_KEY` = '$RK' 
               ORDER BY `dd` asc 
               limit 5) as x 
order by `dd` desc
```

Comment: Surely your second example will select the *first* 5?  You'd need to use the first query as the subquery and then apply an `ORDER BY` in the parent query simply to change the order of the results.